# auto-validate the initial value of textinput flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc

I need to auto-validate the initial value of the text form field. The validation is worked well! BUT the initial value does not validate at all.
I set the value of `autovalidateMode` to `AutovalidateMode.always,`.

**The code of form is:**

```dart
     Form(
         autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
        child:TextInput(),
     )
```

**the code of TextInput:**

```dart
   class TextInput extends StatelessWidget {
      const TextInput();
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Padding(
          child: BlocSelector<NoteFormCubit, NoteFormState, NoteContent>(
            selector: (state) =>
              return state.noteContent,
            builder: (context, state) {
              return TextFormField(
                initialValue:BlocProvider.of<NoteFormCubit>(context).state.noteContent.getValueOrElse(""),
                // input text stores inside the state
                onChanged: (String value) =>
                    context.read<NoteFormCubit>().textInputNote(textNote: value),
    
                validator: (String? validator) =>
                    BlocProvider.of<NoteFormCubit>(context)
                        .state
                        .noteContent
                        .value
                        .fold(
                          (l) => l.msg,
                          (r) => null,
                        ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```